# Navigate to MTP device in Ubuntu BASH shell - can't cd to SD card

Tags: ubuntu, bash, file-transfer, mtp

Have successfully mounted an MTP device on the desktop in Ubuntu and have figured out where the mount point is.

If I cd to /run/user/999/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A001%2C006%5D$

I see 'SD card'

But this is also what I see on the desktop.
How can I cd INSIDE the SD card to copy photos or videos?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the answer you are seeking is already on the [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/342319/where-are-mtp-mounted-devices-located-in-the-filesystem) Stack Exchange site.

From that article:

```
the mountpoints are in /run/user/$USER/gvfs/ and are named after the
protocol, connection type and address they use. Which makes things 
more difficult, because the connection address may change every time 
you replug the device, even if it is the same port. If you have the 
same device twice it gets even worse.
```

If that is not sufficient, I suggest you look at `jmtpfs`.  I have not used it myself, but it sounds like if you installed it, it would do what you want

From the `yum info` details for `jmtpfs`:

```
[user@host ~]$ yum info jmtpfs
...
Available Packages
Name        : jmtpfs
Arch        : x86_64
Version     : 0.4
Release     : 2.el7
Size        : 59 k
Repo        : epel/x86_64
Summary     : FUSE and libmtp based filesystem for accessing MTP devices
URL         : http://research.jacquette.com/jmtpfs-exchanging-files-between-android-devices-and-linux/
License     : GPLv3
Description : jmtpfs is a FUSE and libmtp based filesystem for accessing MTP (Media
            : Transfer Protocol) devices. It was specifically designed for exchanging
            : files between Linux systems and newer Android devices that support MTP
            : but not USB Mass Storage.
            : 
            : The goal is to create a well behaved filesystem, allowing tools like
            : find and rsync to work as expected. MTP file types are set automatically
            : based on file type detection using libmagic. Setting the file appears to
            : be necessary for some Android apps, like Gallery, to be able to find and
            : use the files.
            : 
            : Since it is meant as an Android file transfer utility, the playlists and
            : other non-file based data are not supported.

[user@host ~]$
```

---

Comment: see my edited question...progress but still unresolved:(

Comment: updated my answer